# asynchronous issues adding to a map in mongoose

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mongoose, maps

I am trying to add my googleID (object) to a map in another mongoose schema. I stringify my user id object, and during my test code I get thrown this error:

```
(node:293528) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: collection validation failed: likes.5dbf6205bdcd5e5f78536447: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "110840542851551561690" at path "likes.$*"
    at new ValidationError (C:\files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:30:11)
    at model.Document.invalidate (C:\files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2333:32)
    at Map.set (C:\files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\map.js:71:26)
    at C:\files\app.js:123:30
    at C:\files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4589:16
    at C:\files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4323:12
    at process.nextTick (C:\files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2805:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
(node:293528) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:293528) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**My Post request from client.js:**

```
const likesForm = document.getElementById("test");
likesForm.addEventListener("submit", function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  console.log(event.target.id)
  const [likeString, itemId] = evt.target.id.split("-");
  vote(
    likeString === "like"
      ? "1"
      : "-1",
    itemId
  );
}, false);

async function vote (voteInc, itemId) {
  const route = `/like/${itemId}`;

  const response = await fetch(route, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({"like": voteInc}),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
  });

const result = await response.json();

console.log(result);
}
```

**Server-side post:**

```
app.post("/like/:id",(req,res)=>{
  const id = req.params.id;
  const like = req.body.like;
  console.log(like);
  console.log(id);
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    linkscr.user.findById(req.user.id, (e,foundUser)=>{
      if(e){
        console.log(e);
      }else{
        //if like = 1
        if(like==1){
            linkscr.collection.findById(id, function(error,result){
              if(error){
                console.log(error);
              }else{
                result.likes.set(foundUser._id.toString(),foundUser.googleId);
                result.save();
              }
            })
            console.log("not voted yet. Add 1 and added to like");
        }else{
          linkscr.collection.findById(id, function(error,result){
            if(error){
              console.log(error);
            }else{
              result.dislikes.set(foundUser._id.toString(),foundUser.googleId);
              result.save();
            }
          })
          console.log("not voted yet. Add 1 and added to dislike");   
        };
      };
    });
  }else{
    res.redirect("/");
  }
});
```

**My likes/dislikes schema:**

```
likes        : { 
  type: Map, 
  of: { 
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User" }
    },
dislikes     : { 
  type: Map, 
  of: { 
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User" }
    },
```

**How the Schema is initially saved:**

```
likes        : {[User._id]:User},
dislikes     : {},
```

Thanks for any and all help. You're my only hope Stack!

I first thought this was a mongoose issue with how i was treat my objects but it looks like this is more to do with the async stuff. Admittedly that's my biggest weakness in programming at the time writing this.

**EDIT:** From what I'm looking at from documentation mongoose can't set objects only strings. Mongo can not mongoose.

**Edit 2:** My bad I put in the wrong Id in the wrong place. `foundUser._id.toString() ,foundUser`

Comment: What is the difference between `linkscr.user.` and `linkscr. collection.`? Are the 2 different model? You could have make it look simple by using `async/await`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create maps in mongoose, the key **Must be in the form of a string. Additionally Your schema (which wasn't initially shared) wanted the object_id not the google passportID. For the sake of helping out future generations I will provide an edit in the original post. Simplifying with foundUser will work in this case.

`result.likes.set(foundUser._id.toString(), foundUser);`

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Comment: Apologies. I'll edit my answer to provide explanation.